# What is the growth factor influenced by?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

If I model the cooling of a cup of coffee with the differential equation

$$ T'(t)= -a(T(t)-U)$$
where $U$ is the surrounding temperature and $T(t)$ the temperature of the coffee after $t$ minutes. What can the factor $a$ depend on? Does it depend on pressure of the environment? Isolation of the cup?

Comment: It’s more of a relaxation factor than a growth factor.

Comment: thanks, but what does it depend on? Isolation of the cup? Does it depend on the outside pressure?

Comment: It depends on the surface area and the [heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient). I suppose the heat transfer coefficient depends on the density and thus on the pressure. For example, I would expect dense air to conduct heat more easily than thin air.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on heat conduction through the wall of the cup and convective heat transfer exterior to the cup.  The convective heat transfer can be a combination of natural convection (caused by buoyancy of the air adjacent to the cup) and forced convection (caused by circulation of the air within the room).  So, in addition to the physical properties of the air, it also depends on the air currents in the room.